# I cant update other records than first in database via axios&postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

for some unknown reasons I can update only first record in database even if i can GET  all of them without any problem.. Here is how it looks: [image]
To be more clear: Names are unique thats why I use them instead of id, I change url in postman to update some record but I can update only the first one. Its the same with frontend, while I click on other "PAPP" it returns me valid url but invalid data..

The code:

```
router.put("/:name", (req, res, next) => {
  Papp.findOneAndUpdate({ _pappName: req.params.pappName }, req.body, {
    new: true
  }).then(function(state) {
    res.send(state);
  });
});
```

Schema code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const pappSchema = new Schema({
  pappName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  maintanceName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  maintanceIsOn: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  autosearchName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  autosearchValue: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  commentName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  commentValue: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = Papp = mongoose.model("Papp", pappSchema);
```

Comment: put your `findOneAndUpdate` function as well.. Paste the code,not the screenshot

Comment: Edited as you wished!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request params's name is `name` but you are using `req.params.pappName` in your code. So replace `req.params.pappName`  with `req.params.name`.
Also use `pappName` instead of `_pappName` in the filter query.

```js
router.put("/:name", (req, res, next) => {
  Papp.findOneAndUpdate({ pappName: req.params.name }, req.body, {
    new: true
  }).then(function(state) {
    res.send(state);
  });
});
```

Comment: If I do like you say it returns me empty string of data :/

Comment: @Goteii can you add your Papp schema code to the question?

Comment: Sure, give me a second